# Key Error even though key IS in dictionary?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, variables

Dictionary:
[section of dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrdIr.png)

My Code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3BYE.png)

Error says:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di8yv.png)

So how come the date key works fine but for freq it fails?

ps. my first time posting, so am very sorry for the sloppy structure of the post

Comment: Irreproducible for me

Comment: One of the day dicts doesn't have that key

Comment: Is it possible that the key is not in **all** objects?

Comment: Maybe some `day n` is missing the `freq` parameter.

Comment: all the day(n)s in dictionary have ""freq" key. I scrolled down and confirmed it myself. Just posting a section of the dictionary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only happen when one of your day is missing the `freq` parameter.

Try catching the day in which the error is happening. Then manually check that particular entry.

```
date_list = []
frequency_list = []
try:
    for i in obj:
         date = obj[i]["date"]
         frequency = obj[i]["freq"]

         date_list.append(date)
         frequency_list.append(frequency)
except:
    print(i)
```